# How to find the index of an object in an array by checking property value in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I have an array like:

```
$scope.myArray = [{
  columnName: "processed1",
  dataType: "char"
}, {
  columnName: "processed2",
  dataType: "char"
}, {
  columnName: "processed3",
  dataType: "char"
}];
```

I want find the `index` of `object` which property value satisfy **"processed2"**

How can I do it? I tried using `array.indexOf()` method but I got **response -1**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Use [`Array#findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex), *The `findIndex()` method returns an index in the array, if an element in the array satisfies the provided testing function. Otherwise -1 is returned.*

`Array#indexOf` will fail as `array` contains `objects`, `indexOf()` tests the element using `triple-equals operator` and `object` is equals to `object` if it refers to same `memory-location`

```js
var myArray = [{
  columnName: "processed1",
  dataType: "char"
}, {
  columnName: "processed2",
  dataType: "char"
}, {
  columnName: "processed3",
  dataType: "char"
}];
var index = myArray.findIndex(function(el) {
  return el.columnName == 'processed2';
});
console.log(index);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple for loop.

```
for(var i=0;i < $scope.myArray.length; i++)
{
  if($scope.myArray[i].columnName == 'processed2') {
    // Do something with found item
    break;
  }
}
```